# How to swap column order in csv file using awk?

Tags: awk, csv

I want to change order of this CSV

```
92000,X,19.30,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00,19.29,
00293,X,40.64,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00,40.49,
00293,X,80.95,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00,80.49,
00293,X,41.60,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00,41.49,
```

Like this;

```
92000,X,19.30,19.29,,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00
00293,X,40.64,40.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,80.95,80.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,41.60,41.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00
```

I tried so many `awk` commands but couldn't make it. Can someone show me how to do it?

If the original order of the fields is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, then the new order should be 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4 (note 5, 6, 4 at the end).

Comment: Could you show what you tried? It seems straightforward, so your attempt would help us explain where you went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to swap columns in the following way:

- Column 4 is to become Column 6
- Column 5 is to become Column 4
- Column 6 (empty) is to become Column 5

It should be fairly easy with  `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {tmp4=$4;tmp5=$5;tmp6=$6;$4=tmp5;$5=tmp6;$6=tmp4}1' input.csv
```

- This will set the input and output field separator to `,`.
- It will then store the *current* content of columns 4, 5 and 6 in temporary variables `tmp4`, `tmp5` and `tmp6`, respectively, and then re-assign the columns `$4`, `$5` and `$6` according to the above list.
- The seemingly "stray" `1` outside of the rule block instructs `awk` to print the current line including all modifications made so far.

Note that by default, `awk` will not perform in-place modification of the file, but only print to the console, so you will have to redirect to an output file and possibly rename. If you have a sufficiently recent version of GNU `awk` that understands the `-i inplace` extension, you can also instruct `awk` to directly modify the file:

```
awk -i inplace ' .... ' input.csv
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged this with [csv](/questions/tagged/csv), I would use a CSV-aware tool, such as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`), rather than `awk`.

To change the order of the last three fields in your header-less CSV file so that the 4th field is moved to the end:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N reorder -e -f 4 file
92000,X,19.30,19.29,,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00
00293,X,40.64,40.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,80.95,80.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,41.60,41.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00
```

Another CSV-aware tool that would easily perform this tasks is `csvcut` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bash
$ csvcut -c 1,2,3,5,6,4 file
92000,X,19.30,19.29,,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00
00293,X,40.64,40.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,80.95,80.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,41.60,41.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`xsv`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv):

```
$ xsv select 1-3,5,6,4 file
92000,X,19.30,19.29,,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00
00293,X,40.64,40.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,80.95,80.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,41.60,41.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00
```

This reorders the columns as required using `xsv`'s `select`command.

Answer (score 3):

A little trick with the `column` command on Linux:

```bash
$ column -ts, -o, -O 1,2,3,5,6 file.csv 
92000,X,19.30,19.29,,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00
00293,X,40.64,40.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,80.95,80.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,41.60,41.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00
```

Since there is a separator before the last sixth empty field, and therefore may rearrange empty field with a separator.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$4}' file.csv 
92000,X,19.30,19.29,,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00
00293,X,40.64,40.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,80.95,80.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,41.60,41.49,,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00
```

i.e. just set the input and output field separators and then print the fields in the order you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put .split(",").[0,1,2,5,4,3].join(",");'  file

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'given .split(",") { put .[0,1,2,5,4,3].join(",") };' file
```

With simple CSV-style input (e.g. no embedded commas/newlines, no blank rows), the Raku answer above is a simple `split`/`join` operation. Either example above works.

The problem becomes a little more complicated if you have blank lines (rows) in the input. Here you have to handle Raku perceiving a `Nil` in String context.

The trailing comma leaves an `""` empty element in the sixth column. Ordinarily Raku's `split` operator has a parameter `:skip-empty` which we could use to differentiate blank line input from filled lines. But because of the trailing comma in the OP's input, we cannot use `:skip-empty` and just `Bool`ify the number of elements. So every row except for truly blank rows has at least 2 `elems` elements after splitting.

Let's use that in the answer. Taking the 2nd solution above, it becomes:

```perl
raku -ne 'given .split(",") { .elems > 1 ?? .[0,1,2,5,4,3].join(",").put !! "".put };'
```

The code above simply Raku's ternary operator `(test) ?? True !! False` to check if rows contain `.elems > 1` after `split`ting.

Sample Input (with blank line):

```
92000,X,19.30,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00,19.29,

00293,X,40.64,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00,40.49,
00293,X,80.95,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00,80.49,
00293,X,41.60,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00,41.49,
```

Sample Output for last code example (first two examples above handle Sample Input without blank lines):

```
92000,X,19.30,,19.29,2022-03-01 05:31:58.990562+00

00293,X,40.64,,40.49,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,80.95,,80.49,2021-09-30 13:10:32.084467+00
00293,X,41.60,,41.49,2021-09-30 13:10:32.739939+00
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary
https://raku.org